# A question about sequence convergence in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-derivative, lp-spaces

If $u_m\rightarrow u$ in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)\times H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$(weak) and $u_m\rightarrow u$ in $L^4(\mathbb{R}^n)\times L^4(\mathbb{R}^n)$, denote $u_m=(u_{m,1},u_{m,2})$ and $u=(u_{1},u_{2})$, then whether could we get:

$\liminf\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u_{m,1}^2u_{m,2}^2\,dx   \rightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u_1^2u_2^2\,dx$  under the condition that

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\nabla u_{m,1}|^2+u_{m,1}^2\,dx -\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u_{m,1}^4+u_{m,1}^2u_{m,2}^2\,dx$  and

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\nabla u_{m,2}|^2+u_{m,2}^2\,dx -\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u_{m,1}^4+u_{m,1}^2u_{m,2}^2\,dx$

I encountered this conclusion in a paper but I can't figure out how to prove it.   Thanks for any help!!

Comment: This is not true unless you assume that the supports of all the $u_m$'s are contained in a fixed compact set or some other additional condition.

Comment: Thanks! I will soon edit this question and give the initial form in the paper !